# How to MAX(COUNT(x)) in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by

I have an SQLite table `blog_posts`. Every blog post has an `id` and `blog_id`.

If I want to know how many blog posts every blog has:

```
SELECT blog_id, count(1) posts FROM blog_posts group by blog_id
```

What do I do if I want to know how many posts the blog with the most posts has? (I don't need the `blog_id`.) Apparently this is illegal:

```
SELECT max(count(1)) posts FROM blog_posts group by blog_id
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, but I don't see it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other solution:

```
select count(*) as Result from blog_posts
group by blog_id
order by Result desc
limit 1
```

I'm not sure which solution would run faster, if this one or the one with the subquery.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I came up with too. It looks simpler, so I assumes it's faster, but that doesn't matter. Duh =) Thanks

Comment: As per the question this answer may be wrong, because in case there is an equality between two or more blogs, it only shows one case, right? The subquery may be safest to use, but I am not an expert.

Comment: @YannisDran Your comment makes no sense. The question is _What do I do if I want to know how many posts the blog with the most posts has?_ If 2 or more posts are tied for the top, the amount they have is the same. So it doesn't matter which of them you're counting, you will get the same result. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a subquery.  Here's how you do it:

1. get the number of posts for each blog
2. select the maximum number of posts

Example:

```
select max(num_posts) as max_posts
from (
  select blog_id, count(*) as num_posts 
  from blog_posts 
  group by blog_id
) a
```

(The subquery is in the `(...)`).

NB:  I'm not a SQLite power user and so I don't know if this works, but the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) indicate that subqueries are supported.

Comment: Nice. You can remove the last "a" as in SQLite is is not necessary to name subqueries (as in MySql). And you can also remove blod_id from select statement.

Comment: *(I can't believe I spelled `blog_id` wrong.)*  I adopted the practice of always giving aliases to subqueries so that I never have to think about it, either way, again.